# Create multi page component with React

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-router

My question is not about react-router, I made a request to an API, and its data is extremely huge to be in one page only, so I need a way to automatically generate more pages to save the data in them.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have page no in the URL like `/list?page=1` and based on the page number you can get the value from store to display the data.

Comment: The store doesn't have page numbers. Even the data doesn't include an id for each item in it.